# Enable text box while perform events in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using ng-repeat to printing data.here i added one replay button.based on reply button enable text box under replay button.

but when i click replay button text boxes are enable all the replay buttons.

Thank you...!

**Controller Code**

```
getForumOnIdAnswer(fAnsId);
        function getForumOnIdAnswer (fAnsId){
            ForumRepository.getForumOnIdAnswer(fAnsId)
            .then(function (response){
                scope.forumAnswer=response;
            },
             function(errResponse){
                 console.error('Error while fetching forumAnser');
             }
            );
        };
```

**html code**

```
<div ng-repeat="forumAnswerData in forumAnswer">
                    <div class="panel-group">
                        <div class="panel panel-success">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <a href="">{{forumAnswerData.farmer.firstName}}</a>
                                <div class="pull-right">{{ forumAnswerData.answerDate |
                                    date:"MM/dd/yyyy 'at' h:mma" }}</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body">{{forumAnswerData.answer}}</div>
                            <div class="panel-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="">Reply</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

[image: view]

Comment: share your code please!

Comment: [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: i belive, your are usina var  out from object repeated, try to create a var in same object repeated as the button,please share your code and will help you better

Comment: @Hadi shared more code

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón i'm using ng-repeat.here how to enable text box clicking button

Comment: @umapathi, please share your html code, and will help you better, andyou put your js will be better

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón now i added my html code also.check it once

Comment: try providing a unique id to your button and text-box everytime you repeat them, then use `ng-show' directive along with those id's to to open textbox on button click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be like this. just for enabling textbox.

```html
<div ng-repeat="forumAnswerData in forumAnswer">
  <div class="panel-group">
    <div class="panel panel-success">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <a href="">{{forumAnswerData.farmer.firstName}}</a>
        <div class="pull-right">{{ forumAnswerData.answerDate | date:"MM/dd/yyyy 'at' h:mma" }}</div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">{{forumAnswerData.answer}}</div>
      <div class="panel-footer">
        <textarea ng-model="yourModel" ng-show="$index ==currentTextBox"></textarea>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="currentTextBox = $index">Reply</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: under replay button.like stack overflow add comment

Answer (score 0):

the code i think will work, using your own repeater in view is:

```
<div ng-repeat="forumAnswerData in forumAnswer" ng-init="forumAnswerData.buttonEnabled=false;">
                    <div class="panel-group" ng-click="forumAnswerData.buttonEnabled=true">
                        <div class="panel panel-success">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <a href="">{{forumAnswerData.farmer.firstName}}</a>
                                <div class="pull-right">{{ forumAnswerData.answerDate |
                                    date:"MM/dd/yyyy 'at' h:mma" }}</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body">{{forumAnswerData.answer}}</div>
                            <div class="panel-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="" ng-disabled="forumAnswerData.buttonEnabled">Reply</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Expect it helps you

Comment: the view is working and when i click button is disabled.but text box not displayed

Comment: I'm asking text box enable when i click button.but here button is disabled.can you add some more code for text box.